# Can I increase yield from blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there some way to increase the yield from every block? E.G. 5 diamonds from diamond ore instead of one.

Answers for either version of Minecraft are fine.

Edit: mods/trainers would be great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Fortune enchantment can increase the amount of drops from an ore, up to 4 times as much. Fortune ranges in level from I to III.

Keep in mind that Fortune is incompatible with Silk Touch.

Answer (score 0):

There's no enchantment that will allow you to get 2 or more block in vanilla minecraft. All Ores excluding iron and gold ore can give more than 1 drop if you use Fortune pickaxe. Also you can use fortune tools to increase the drops from wheat(seeds), potato, carrots, etc.